# update a variable inside loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, promise

I am trying to update var inside a loop that is then returned to a promise.  But the var fails to update.  So far I have tried this,

```
var queryPromise = cronie.find({}).
    where('id').equals(req.user._id).
    exec();  //mongoose promise


    queryPromise.then(function(timer) { 
        for (var i = 0, len = timer.length; i < len; i++) {
            x = moment.unix(timer[i].nextTick).format('dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY h:mm:ss A');  //convert to human;
            console.log(x);
            timer[i].nextTick = x;
            console.log(timer[i].nextTick);
          }

          return timer;
    }).then(function(timer) { 
        res.render('dash.ejs', {
            user: req.user,
            timer: timer
        });

    });
});
```

This is the outputs:

```
0|server   | Monday, May 21st, 2018 11:00:00 PM
0|server   | 1526943600
0|server   | Monday, May 21st, 2018 7:28:22 PM
0|server   | 1526930902
0|server   | Monday, May 21st, 2018 7:28:22 PM
0|server   | 1526930902
0|server   | Monday, May 21st, 2018 7:28:22 PM
0|server   | 1526930902
0|server   | Monday, May 21st, 2018 7:28:22 PM
0|server   | 1526930902
```

But `timer[i].nextTick` remains unchanged.  How do I update it before sending it to render so that users can see human time instead of a stamp?

**UPDATE**  Slice of the timer array

```
0|server   |   { _id: 5b031dd6c0d99f79946f263f,
0|server   |     id: '5b031dd5c0d99f79946f263a',
0|server   |     lastTick: 1526930902,
0|server   |     nextTick: 1526930902,
0|server   |     lastUpdate: 1526930902,
0|server   |     __v: 0,
0|server   |     timerStatus: false,
0|server   |     emailStatus: false }
```

**UPDATE 2**

adding

```
timer[i].date =  moment.unix(timer[i].nextTick).format('dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY h:mm:ss A');
```

then changing ejs to `timer.date works`.  But assigining `nextTick` still does not.

Comment: If you can, leave the `.nextTick` property as it is and set another property, say `.nextTick_` to the formatted version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) to make the returned document be a plain javascript object. This way you can manipulate it at will, later on.

```
var queryPromise = cronie.find({}).
    where('id').equals(req.user._id).
    lean(). // make returned document be a plain js object
    exec();  //mongoose promise
```

> Documents returned from queries with the `lean` option enabled are plain javascript objects, not MongooseDocuments. **They have no `save` method, getters/setters or other Mongoose magic applied**.

Comment: This is correct.  I realized that when I could update it to a Number and set `timer[i].nextTick = 5555`  but not `timer[i].nextTick = "aaa"` as `timer[i].nextTick` is set to `Number` in the schema.  I could not find a work around. Ty